# What is the name of this marble game?

Tags: identify-this-game

My friends play this marble game often, but we don't know the name of it.

You play with 2 decks of cards. Play in 2 or 3 teams of 2 players each. (The image below is setup for 2 teams of 2.)

Goal is to get both players on the team all filled up in their base. Have to get into the base with an exact number.

Each player takes turns playing cards:

- A: Forward 1 or out of start
- K: Back 1 or out of start
- Q: Forward 12 or out of start
- J: Switch
- 3: Back 3
- Forward number on card

Some of the rules include:

- Have to use an A/K/Q to move out of start before any cards can be played to move a marble any further.
- Can't pass your teammate
- Can use the backwards cards from the start to loop around to the end of the board.
- Landing on an opponent puts them back to start
- Black places are safeties

And a handful of other rules.

What is the name of this game?

[image: marble game board]

Comment: Hey Jon!  Welcome to the site, I don't recognize the game, but with your great description I hope that someone will be able to help you out.

Comment: Looks a lot like a variant on Joker Marbles - I can't find a board or a ruleset that looks exactly the same so far, but there's a lot of variation so this isn't that surprising.  Was this a commercially produced game, do you happen to know?

Comment: @thesunneversets: This particular board was made by an individual. So, yes, it might have a slightly different layout of the spaces.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The name of the game is **[Dog](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/2633/dog)** or **Brändi Dog**. It's a little bit like Parchesi, except you use cards and not dice to go.

You can play it on **[BrettSpielWelt](http://www.brettspielwelt.de/Spiele/Dog/)** for free, if you want to confirm it's the good game.

Comment: Finally! It looks like the rules we play with or a slight variation on Dog, but it is very, very close. So I'm guessing the rules we play with were more mistakes than intentional customization. Nice work!

Comment: I have to respectfully disagree that it is called Dog. It's pretty similar, but one of the main differences is the starting points for the players. In Dog, each player has their own starting point, however in the game shown above each player brings their marble out and starts around the board at the same starting point. Having the same starting point adds a much different dynamic to the game.

Comment: @sheephead15 Welcome to stackexchange!  I think the rules to Dog are slightly different, and yes the rules listed above do change the dynamic some, but I don't think drastically enough that it is another game. Unless you can offer up a better reference that matches the rules in the question exactly?

Answer (score 0):

We have a friend who has a similar game, but it's more like Sorry. It's got the whole home-made wood board and marbles and playing cards as components as well. Maybe that helps.

Comment: It is similar in idea to _Sorry!_ yes, but no this isn't the Milton Bradley game.

Comment: This comment on the Aggravation BGG entry, discusses card-based rules that might also point you in the right direction - http://www.boardgamegeek.com/article/8121731#8121731

Comment: I'm confused. Are you talking about an Aggravation-based customization of _Sorry!_? Or the game I posted in my question is similar to Aggrevation? In other words, why was this comment put under this Answer and not under the Question?

Comment: I placed it under Answers because it was a comment I made after an answer, and definitely not an answer in itself, in addition, the game that I was suggesting was not really like sorry, and more like Aggravation/Parchisi....